# CSS slideshow - How can I add a link to the image?

Tags: css, slideshow

How can I add a link to these images. I've tried many variations of slideshows but find when I add links it starts not displaying every other image. In my code below I have the links commented out. If I remove the links the images display fine.

I have repeated the images twice just trying to debug and have _parent tag in the link because this page will be displayed in an iframe.

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time reading this post.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
    <a href="" target="_parent"><img class='photo' src="featuredProducts/On-Semi-Python-sensors-sm.png"/></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider {
    margin: 0;
    width: 180px;
    height: 1504px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.photo {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: round 16s infinite;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes round {
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.slider img:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
    -o-animation-delay: 8s;
    animation-delay: 8s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
    -o-animation-delay: 4s;
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

Comment: Cleaned up the CSS that had no linefeeds

Comment: what do u mean by `when I add links the images don't display correctly` ?

Comment: Without links it displays the 4 images. When I add the links. Only every other image is displayed in the slide show. It looks like one might be actually be displaying in the background very briefly.

Comment: Please consider upvoting helpful answers to be thankful of time and effort people invest on your problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is correctly with your links.
You have `<img>` inside anchor, but you try to hide img and leaves its parent anchor visible.
It is impossiple after that to make another image visible until the left parent anchor is hidden. Thus you see a blank white area until time passes to hide this left anchor and a new img can appear.
Solution is to hide the parent anchor of each img to have the right effect.
There are two steps:
HTML : Change class photo from img to anchor
CSS : Change selector to .slider a:nth-child(...)

This modified code works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="slider">
<!--
<img class='photo' src="1.jpg" alt="" />
<img class='photo' src="2.jpg" alt="" />
<img class='photo' src="3.jpg" alt="" />
-->
<a class='photo' href="http://www.google.com" target="_parent" ><img         src="1.jpg" alt="On Semi PYTHON sensors" /></a>
<a class='photo' href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_parent" ><img src="2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class='photo' href="http://www.pinterest.com" target="_parent" ><img src="3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class='photo' href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_parent" ><img src="4.jpg" alt="" /></a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.slider { margin: 0; width: 180px; height: 1504px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
.photo { position: absolute; -webkit-animation: round 16s infinite; opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
@-webkit-keyframes round { 25% { opacity: 1; } 40% { opacity: 0; } }

.slider a:nth-child(4) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
-moz-animation-delay: 12s;
-ms-animation-delay: 12s;
-o-animation-delay: 12s;
animation-delay: 12s;
}

.slider a:nth-child(3) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
-moz-animation-delay: 8s;
-ms-animation-delay: 8s;
-o-animation-delay: 8s;
animation-delay: 8s;
}

.slider a:nth-child(2) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
-moz-animation-delay: 4s;
-ms-animation-delay: 4s;
-o-animation-delay: 4s;
animation-delay: 4s;
}

.slider a:nth-child(1) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0s;
-ms-animation-delay: 0s;
-o-animation-delay: 0s;
animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution fixed the image display, but I need to link to separate pages for the images. Even when another image is displayed, the first link is active - in other words the links aren't mapping link2 with image2, link3 with image3...  I added the CSS as described and moved class='photo' to the anchor tag. If you have any ideas how to fix the links I would appreciate it.  To avoid confusion I posted code changes from John's answer but did not post your solution yet.

Comment: That works great. I tore my hair out on it!  I'm very relieved. Thank You so much for your time and help. Sorry for my delay in getting back to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because of `position: absolute` for the images with `photo` class. You my remove the `position: absolute` from `photo` and add it to `a` elements instead.

```
.slider a{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
.photo {
    -webkit-animation: round 16s infinite;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace .slide img with .slide a

```css
.slider {
  margin: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 1504px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: round 16s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes round {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.slider a:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

.slider a:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
  -o-animation-delay: 8s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

.slider a:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.slider a:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <a href="cameras/cameras-with-OnSemi-Python-sensors.php" target="_parent"><img class='photo' src="http://i.imgur.com/IMiabf0.jpg" alt="On Semi PYTHON sensors" /></a>

  <a href="cameras/cameras-with-OnSemi-Python-sensors.php" target="_parent"><img class='photo' src="http://i.imgur.com/NqCM7jH.jpg" alt="" /></a>


  <a href="cameras/cameras-with-OnSemi-Python-sensors.php" target="_parent"><img class='photo' src="http://i.imgur.com/cjN8Qoa.jpg" alt="" /></a>


  <a href="cameras/cameras-with-OnSemi-Python-sensors.php" target="_parent"><img class='photo' src="http://i.imgur.com/WQ2RS6O.png" alt="" /></a>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much that helps a lot. I would like each image to link to a different page.  When an new  image is displayed the link doesn't change. I posted updated  code. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The code below helped. The images display nicely, but I need to link to separate pages for the images. Even when another image is displayed, the first link is active - in other words the links aren't mapping link2 with image2, link3 with image3...

Please take a look below and let me know if you see how to fix it. Thank you!

```css
.slider {
  margin: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 1504px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.slider a {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: round 16s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes round {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.slider a:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

.slider a:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
  -o-animation-delay: 8s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

.slider a:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.slider a:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <a href="link1.php" target="_parent"><img class='photo' src="http://i.imgur.com/IMiabf0.jpg" alt="On Semi PYTHON sensors" /></a>

  <a href="link2.php" target="_parent"><img class='photo' src="http://i.imgur.com/NqCM7jH.jpg" alt="" /></a>


  <a href="link3.php" target="_parent"><img class='photo' src="http://i.imgur.com/cjN8Qoa.jpg" alt="" /></a>


  <a href="link4.php" target="_parent"><img class='photo' src="http://i.imgur.com/WQ2RS6O.png" alt="" /></a>


</div>
```